# Tidy2.0 extension

Tags: php, tidy, php-extension, htmltidy

So I'm trying to get Tidy2.0 installed on my Karmic, following this guide:
http://www.howtoforge.com/forums/archive/index.php/t-7395.html

I figured everything would work, but it seems the source for Tidy2.0 is no longer live:
http://support.office-shadow.com/installer/tidy2.0.tar.gz

That site is still live though (office-shadow.com, namely), but it doesn't seem like they're hosting the extension anymore. Thus, I'm hoping someone here has it sitting somewhere on a box. Please? Help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo aptitude install php5-dev libtidy-dev
#you may have to install other libs, like gcc, build-essential, etc.
#see the guides on how to compile PHP, for instance
svn co http://svn.php.net/repository/php/php-src/branches/PHP_5_3/ext/tidy/
cd tidy
phpize
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Basically, I just replaced http://support.office-shadow.com/installer/tidy2.0.tar.gz with the repository location. If you're using PHP 5.2, replace PHP_5_3 with PHP_5_2.

Comment: Are you sure that works the same as the one hosted by office-shadow.com ?